# Функция, удаляющая из списка каждый второй элемент

Tags: haskell

Как написать функцию, удаляющую из списка каждый второй элемент?

Answer (score 1):

```
f []       = []         -- если список пустой то результат пустой список
f (x:[])   = [x]        -- если список состоит из одного элемента то 
                        -- результат список из одного элемента
f (x:_:xs) = (x: f xs)  -- иначе взять два элемента и вернуть список из 
                        -- первого элемента и списка полученного применением 
                        -- к остатку функции удаляющей каждый второй элемент
```

Answer (score -1):

Нужно мыслить рекурсивно. Взять один элемент, пропустить 2 (от начала), повторить:

```
f [] = []
f x = take 1 x ++ f (drop 2 x)
```

https://ideone.com/C1PS3S